# SOLVED A little problem with fancyhdr `\leftmark` in `article` document

Tags: packages, fancyhdr

I am having a problem with the `\leftmark` command of the `fancyhdr` package. This is a `tex` sample

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{first section}
First paragraph

\section{second section}
Second paragraph

\end{document}
```

This is the output

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that latex (compiling with `lualatex`) print `SECOND CHAPTER` instead of `FIRST CHAPTER`, as the `\leftmark` should give the **current** section in `article` mode. If i try to use the builtin `\pagestyle{headings}`, changing the document like so:

```
...

\pagestyle{headings}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{}
%\rhead{\leftmark}

...
```

then the output is as expected:

[image]

What should I try?

Comment: `\leftmark` gives the last mark on a page. You could use the extramarks package and use the `\firstleftmark` instead. Or you can redefine \sectionmark and use \rightmark.

Comment: That was easy.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is better to post your last edit as an answer and accept it to keep the number of unanswered questions as low as possible.

Comment: If you found the answer after a comment, either ask the person who commented to write up a short answer or write one yourself. Then accept the answer (possibly after a waiting time). That way the answer is marked as resolved by the system. That is usually preferred over editing the title to say 'solved'. It also helps future visitors because they can easily identify the question and find the answer in the answer section. (In a way the 'solved' in the title is noise and takes away from the other, more important words in the title.)